# Load external html file to div and use its js functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some div:

```
<div id='dialog'></div>
```

Now I want to load into this div an external html file and use its js functions.

I know I can load it using jQuery.Load() and it works fine, the problem is that I want to use the html js functions.

The main problem is that I have several divs which I load this html file into them and I want that when I'm activating js function it will only work on the specific div.

Comment: i think you can also use $.ajax and then on success callback load entire HTML response to specific divs.

Answer (score 0):

Pass parameter to view that you are loading that will indicate container of the loaded view:

```
jQuery.Load(url, { containerId: 'dialog' })
```

Comment: ok, and then how can I use the js functions? how can i be sure that I'm using the functions only for the specific div?

Comment: If the view is dynamic, then you can handle container variable with server side language. Is the view you are loading static or dynamic?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, I load a static html file into a div I created on run-time using jQuery, is it possible that you will write simple example of how to use?

Comment: javascript which you are activating is written inside html file?

Answer (score 0):

I remember I had the problem back when jQuery1.4 was issued. In that version, `.load()` suddendly began stripping out the js when a target container was specified.

What I did at that time :

1. separate html and js in different files (let's say *myhtml.html* and *myjs.js* ), or views
2. have my js file act as a js module, with a public entry point function (say `initContent`) taking a jQuery element as a parameter
3. have an invisible link in *myhtml.html*, namely `<a href="myjs.js#initContent" class="dynamicJs" style="display:none;"></a>`
4. after loading *myhtml.html* into my target div, search for `$('a.dynamicJs')` in my target div to extract js url, and entry point function from the `href`
5. if the js had not previously been loaded, dynamically load the js into the page trhough an ajax call
6. dynamically call the entry point function with the target div as parameter

This also worked with css. 
It required some time to tweak it on all navigators (limited number of css sections on IE, different way to dynamically call a function), and I ended with much more code I expected in the first place. It also required a lot of refactoring of my html/js modules (but I must confess I ended having a code that was really cleaner)

I'm sure there are frameworks that handle this kind of situation way better by now. But this is what I came up with at that time.

Hope this will help