# iframe contentWindow throws Access Denied error after shortening document.domain

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, dynamic, access-denied

I create an IFRAME dynamically in the following way:

```
var wrapUpIframe = document.createElement("iframe");
wrapUpIframe.id = 'WrapUpDialog3';
wrapUpIframe.src = 'WrapUpDialog.html';    
document.body.appendChild(wrapUpIframe);
```

after the dynamic creation my `document.domain` is being shortened from `Servername.dc.com` to only `dc.com`,

but when I try to access `contentWindow` I got an Access is denied error:

```
document.getElementById("WrapUpDialog3").contentWindow.SomeFunction();
```

**Note:** When I define the IFRAME statically in the HTML it works fine.
I also tried to change my IFRAME `document.domain` in the following way:

```
WrapUpDialog3.document.domain = dc.com;
```

I checked both `document.domain` and my IFRAME domain and they are both identical.

What can I do?

I'm working with IE9.

Comment: In what browser do you get this behavior? If I type your code into the Chrome debugger I can access `el.contentWindow` fine. Note that not just the domain needs to match but the full origin, so you might try to compare `document.location.origin` of the two windows.

Comment: @nhaldimann I work with IE9

Comment: This has been answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe

Bertrand

Comment: @BertrandLefort But he said the origin is the same.

Comment: What is `WrapUpDialog3`? And how do you access `contentWindow`? If you could post a more complete example then we might be able to help you better.

Comment: @MartijndeMilliano WrapUpDialog3 is just my iFrame id and I added an example to the use in my question

Comment: @DorCohen Have you tried to access the `iframe` via `frames` collection, like `window.frames[0].SomeFunction();`.

Comment: What was the thing that solved the issue? There's a bunch of tips in the accepted answer...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First take a look at the correct answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879192/jquery-iframe-access-denied-in-ie-on-some-pages).  It looks to me like that could be your issue.

If not that then maybe this quick hack I saw from another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842572/how-to-deal-with-setting-dynamic-iframe-content-dynamically) might help.

```
 var frame = $('<iframe>')
.attr('id', 'myIframe')
.addClass('someClass')
.attr('src', 'javascript:(function () {' +'document.open();document.domain=\'myDomain.net\';document.close();' + '})();');
.appendTo($('#someDiv'));
```

Not sure if this is relevant but I also found this on the web [link](http://davidwalsh.name/iframe-permission-denied).

OK, so to respond to your comment.  The javascript function isn't assigning the source, it's setting the document domain which apparently doesn't get done correctly in I.E.

Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886547/access-is-denied-javascript-error-when-trying-to-access-the-document-object-of) for another example and explanation.

So what I would try might be something like this ...

```
var wrapUpIframe = document.createElement("iframe");
wrapUpIframe.id = 'WrapUpDialog3';    
wrapUpIframe.src = setSrc();
document.body.appendChild(wrapUpIframe);

function setSrc(){document.open();document.domain=\'dc.com\';document.close();return 'WrapUpDialog.html';}
```

You might have to play around with how to return the actual url for the iframe after running the function that sets the document domain.  But from what I am seeing this might work for you.

I had a similar issue but not exactly the same problem which is why I can't give you an exact fix. The function setting the document domain was what got me past the access denied error.

You could also add this to your main document to really make sure the domains match.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    document.domain = 'dc.com';
  </script>
```

I also wanted to add a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481251/what-does-document-domain-document-domain-do) for some explanation on explicitly setting the document.domain that I had used before. This was helpful to me in the past. Particularly this quote ...

> Explicitly setting the value indicates intent to "cooperate" with a
>   script on another subdomain (under the same parent domain).

Dor, you may be having a timing issue. I found some code (here) that I just tested that works for me. It makes sure that the iframe is loaded before you try to access the contentWindow.

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.src = "WrapUpDialog.html";

if (iframe.attachEvent){
    iframe.attachEvent("onload", function(){
        alert("Local iframe is now loaded.");
    });
} else {
    iframe.onload = function(){
        alert("Local iframe is now loaded.");
    };
}

document.body.appendChild(iframe);

var iframeWindow = iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument.parentWindow;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my src should be an external html page - WrapUpDialog.html, how can load it using your suggestion?

Comment: Dor, are you trying to load the js functions you mentioned in this question  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14849606/load-external-html-file-to-div-and-use-its-js-functions) in this html page?

Comment: Shame I didn't get the bounty. :)

Comment: Dor, if it was the timing issue that was the problem let me know. I'll  edit my answer so that others know as well.

Answer (score 2):

How do you serve your files? Do you see `file:///` in your address bar? If so, try serving your code using a webserver.

Google Chrome gives an access denied error if I try your code using `file:///`, but it works when served from a local webserver (i.e. the address starts with `http://localhost/`).

Comment: I am using regular HTML page, no files

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not yet accepted any of the answers given you probably still have the problem.

Try setting `document.domain` explicitly in both HTML pages (you seem to be doing this in one page only). This means that as @Vic suggested, you need to add the following javascript code to the HTML that includes the iframe:

```
document.domain = 'dc.com';
```

This means that your code would look like this:

```
document.domain = 'dc.com';
var wrapUpIframe = document.createElement("iframe");
wrapUpIframe.id = 'WrapUpDialog3';
wrapUpIframe.src = 'WrapUpDialog.html';    
document.body.appendChild(wrapUpIframe);
```

Then, in `WrapUpDialog.html` itself (not in the main page because then you would circumvent the security system!) you need to set `document.domain` as well:

```
document.domain = dc.com;
```

So this line of yours will NOT work:

```
WrapUpDialog3.document.domain = 'dc.com';
```

because `WrapUpDialog.html` itself needs to grant permission to its "parent" page to execute its javascript.

There is more info on this page: [What does document.domain = document.domain do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481251/what-does-document-domain-document-domain-do).

Final hint: do try your code using different browsers: IE9, Firefox, Google Chrome. This can help you identify whether you are perhaps dealing with a quirk of one particular browser.